# Exibir apenas palavras com 04 letras em Python

Tags: python, lista, for

Estou aprendendo Python e estou fazendo um exercício, que é esse aqui: *Implemente um programa que solicite do usuário uma lista de palavras (ou seja, strings) e depois exiba na tela, uma por linha, todas as strings de 4 letras nessa lista Python*

Mas estou enroscado e não consegui fazer com que mais de uma palavra fosse exibida. Se puderem me ajudar a esclarecer, eu agradeço. O código que fiz está abaixo.

```
nome = []
print('Olá')
nome.append(input('Digite um nome: '))

for n in nome:
    if len(n) == 4:
        print(n)
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código para validar as palavras com 4 letras e exibi-las está correto, o problema é que você está executando uma vez apenas o código, ou seja, armazena 1 nome, exibe (ou não) e termina o programa com sucesso.

Se você quiser que ele continue pedindo e printando os nomes tem que colocar um laço. Por exemplo, o `while`, assim, enquanto a condição for verdadeira o processo continua.

Tentei entender seu problema e fiz algumas alterações: Criei uma lista para armazenar todos os nomes, coloquei o `while` para continuar pedindo novos nomes enquanto não receber um input vazio e coloquei o print no final, após escapar do laço.

Ahh, e na lista só são adicionados os nomes com exatos 4 caracteres.

```
ListaNome = []
nome = input('Digite um nome: ')

while nome != '':
    if len(nome) == 4:
        ListaNome.append(nome)
    nome = input('Digite um nome: ')
    
for x in range(len(ListaNome)):
    print(ListaNome[x])
```

Comment: Obrigado! Até pensei e tentei aplicar o while, mas não acertei. Me falta muito ainda pra aprender. Mais uma vez te agradeço!

Comment: @dougst procure o canal curso em vídeo no YouTube, do professor Guanabara. Tem um curso de python desde o início que é excelente

Answer (score 1):

A criação da lista vazia 'nome' não é necessária, com o append, vc estava adicionando apenas 1 string na lista, independementemente de quantas palavras fossem inseridas no input, assim, no IF o len(nome) sempre seria 1, não acionando o código dentro do IF.

Segue exemplo:

```
print('Olá')
nome = input("Digite um nome ").split(' ')
for n in nome:
    if len(nome) == 4:
        print(n)
```

.
.
.
.
.
.
.